# aio-pika 2 consumers receive message through fanout not in the same time

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I'm new to RabbitMQ and Pika but I thought that I've clearly understood how it works.

I need to implement this:

Producer creates message and sends through fanout exchange, multiple producers (2 in testing environment) receive same message.

But only 1 consumer receives message at time

*2019-11-29 19:02:44.167549 b'Hello'* - 1st consumer

*2019-11-29 19:02:45.068192 b'Hello'* - 2nd consumer

Producer:

```
    async def main(loop):
        connection = await connect_robust(
            "amqp://guest:guest@192.168.1.3/", loop=loop
        )

        queue_name = "test_queue"
        routing_key = "test_queue"

        # Creating channel
        channel = await connection.channel()

        # Declaring exchange
        exchange = await channel.declare_exchange('test_exchange',
                                                  ExchangeType.FANOUT, auto_delete=True
                                                  )

        # Declaring queue
        queue = await channel.declare_queue(
            queue_name, auto_delete=True
        )

        # Binding queue
        await queue.bind(exchange, routing_key)

        await exchange.publish(
            Message(
                bytes('Hello', 'utf-8'),
                content_type='text/plain',
                headers={'foo': 'bar'}
            ),
            routing_key
        )
    )


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Consumer:

```
    async def main(loop):
            connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(host='192.168.1.3', login='guest', password='guest', loop=loop
                                                       )

            queue_name = "test_queue"

            async with connection:
                # Creating channel
                channel = await connection.channel()

                # Declaring queue
                queue = await channel.declare_queue(
                    queue_name, auto_delete=True
                )

                async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
                    async for message in queue_iter:
                        async with message.process():
                            print(datetime.datetime.now(), message.body)

                            if queue.name in message.body.decode():
                                break


    if __name__ == "__main__":
          loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
          loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
          loop.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm assuming you are running two separate consumer processes.

Each consumer should bind its own queue to the fanout exchange. Don't use a shared queue. One solution is for each consumer to use exclusive queues.

There is no need for the producer to create a queue and bind it to the fanout exchange as long as your consumers start first.

Try this first. Then, if you need to take into account that your producer can start first, it will have to create two queues with well-known names, and bind them. The consumers should do the same thing when they start.